# Django: DateField "This field cannot be blank."

Tags: python, django

I'm posting a rest request like this:

```
{title:some title, recurring:true, day:Wednesday, time:12:30, description:some text}
```

I am not passing the date because the event is recurring and the value should be empty.  The server response is:

```
{"date": ["This field cannot be blank."]}
```

Here is the relevant python code:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    recurring = models.BooleanField()
    day = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    time = models.TimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    venueAddress = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    venueCity = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event

class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
```

I am not completely sure where the message is coming back from. Is my model defined correctly? Do I need extra work in my serializer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the `blank=True` parameter to the definition of your `date` field if you want that field to be optional.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#blank):

> Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Comment: Docs link is broken.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving  - thanks, updated to a newer version.

Answer (score 7):

The first step is to change your field description like so:

```
date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

`null=True` is insufficient because that is only a directive relevant to table creation, not to validation. `null` and `blank` are separate concepts because there are situations where you only want one and not the other.

By the way, in almost all cases a `date` and a `time` field can be compressed into one `DateTimeField`.

Comment: This is probably one of the cases where the date and time field can't be compressed, so this design allows for date to be unset for recurring events.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a library which in turn uses [django.forms.ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

If this is the case, you can add blank=True to your DateField to resolve the issue.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    recurring = models.BooleanField()
    day = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.TimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    venueAddress = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    venueCity = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```